# Git Project Sharing in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

How to share git project in android studio? In Eclipse, we can share Team -> Share Prjects . But I don't know how to share in android sudio on mac platforms. I want to share via local network with ssh.When I checkout other branch,all code are not change ,showing previous branch code.

Comment: you can try from command prompmt --> gitbash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) IDEs, Android Studio has many Git operations built-in. You can access most of them from the "VCS" menu at the top. Here's a more-detailed guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-git-integration.html